# PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping not working

Tags: spring-ws

I have my POJO annotated with `@Endpoint` and `@Payloadroot` and I have `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` in by spring configuration file but I am getting error "no adapter found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both an `EndpointMapping` (which tells Spring-WS *which* endpoint to invoke), and also an `EndpointHandler` (which tells Spring-WS *how* to invoke it).

You have the first one (the `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping`), but you also need an `EndpointHandler`, such as a `PayloadMethodEndpointAdapter`.

From Spring-WS 2.0 onwards, you can just declare `<sws:annotation-driven/>`, and it'll all be taken care of (see [docs for details](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/server.html#server-endpoints)).